# Validate that value isnt in database already

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to validate that the email address entered is not already in my data base. I have the following code:

Heres my form in my html

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
                <input type="text" name="First_name" placeholder="First Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z].{2,}" maxlength="20" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Must be between 2 and 20 characters long and no numbers!')"/>
                <input type="text" name="Last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z']..{2,}" maxlength="20" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Must be between 2 and 20 characters long! and no numbers')"/>
                <input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" name="Email" required placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="30" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Must be a validate Email Address!')"/>
                <input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" name="Email2" required placeholder="Comfirm Email Address" maxlength="30" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Must be a validate Email Address!')"/>
                <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required maxlength="20" required pattern=".{6,}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Must be between 6 and 20 characters long!')"/>
                <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit"/>
              </form>
```

Heres my jquery at the top of the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  //result texts
  var email_error = 'Emails do not match!';
  alert("Hi");
  //when button is clicked
  $('#Submit').click(function(){
    //run the character number check
    if($('#Email').val() != $('#Email2').val()){
      //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '
      $('#emailValidate').html(email_error);
    }else{
      //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check
      check_availability();
    }
  });

});

//function to check username availability
function check_availability(){

    //get the username
    var Email = $('#Email').val();

    //use ajax to run the check
    $.post("checkmail.php", { Email: Email },
      function(result){
        //if the result is 1
        if(result == 1){
          //show that the username is available
          $('#emailValidate').html(Email + ' is Available');
        }else{
          //show that the username is NOT available
          $('#emailValidate').html(Email + ' is not Available');
        }
    });

}
</script>
```

Here is my php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$DB = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $DB);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email = '".$_POST['Email']."'";
$select = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($select);

if($row > 0)) {
  echo 1;
}else 
echo 0;
?>
```

Now when I click submit nothing happens with the logic. For some reason it is not detecting the submit and not evaluating. I used Submit as the id and it is not picking it up. Did I approach this incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see a `validateForm()` function. Nor do you have id's.

Comment: Since `Email` is a text field you must use quotes like: `WHERE Email = '".$_POST['Email']."'";`, notice that your code is also vurnable to sql injection

Comment: $.post("checkmail.php", { Email: Email }, 
where is Email?

Comment: And where does `Email` comes from in `check_availability`?

Comment: Email is from the form. I though that it was able to take that from there? and validate form is from a different function I created that I forgot was there. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @user081608 - Nope not like that, you should give your input fields unique ids and then grab a value like `var Email = $('#Email').val();`

Comment: Oh so I have to grab that in the top of the first function? Also it is not even going in there to get the alert I set.

Comment: One other strange thing is that you check `if(result == 1) {` when you in fact only return `exits` or `notexist` from your php script?

Comment: How does my updated php script look?

Comment: @user081608 - Since you don't even get the alert message, my best guess would be that you have not included `jQuery` before your javascript.

Comment: I include the following line before <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: as per your new edit: You're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` functions, which do not intermix with each other. use the same API from connection to query. all this `$Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']); 
$result = mysql_query('select Email from users where Email = "'. $Email .'"'); 

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){` is not the right functions. Missing an `i` for those, while passing DB connection parameter to certain functions.

Comment: But... your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31505013/1 was using all `mysqli_`, so why the switch/mix of `mysql_`?

Comment: I edited it to match everything now

Comment: you're not doing anything with `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);` and am assuming you want to check if it exists using `mysqli_num_rows`. which your syntax is incorrect. So change that to `$row = mysqli_num_rows($select);` then change `if (mysqli_num_rows > 0)` to `if($row > 0)` if that is the ultimate goal.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Do you think that it is not getting into any of that because the type for my submit is not button?

Comment: maybe, try changing its type

Comment: When I do that nothing happens when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it so that the SQL database column has to be uniqe. Therefore, SQL will do it for you and you can just submit your form. If there is an email that matches the submitted one, SQL will throw a constraint error.

Comment: I already have that but I want to allow the users to just change their email address on the spot. Is that possible with that method?

Comment: @user081608 I would submit the form through JavaScript/jQuery so that if there is an error, you can alert the user and allow them to change the email.